# Tracing relationships between items in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that defines a set of relationships, for example:

```
relationships = {"Fred": ["Mary, John"],
                 "Mary": ["Fred", "Alex"],
                 "John": ["Fred"]
                 "Alex": ["Mary"]}
```

I'd like to build some functionality that, given a name I return a list of all the relationships associated with that name.

A direct relationship is signaled by a Key: Value pair (so Mary is directly related to Fred) and a second level relationship is signaled through a "friend of a friend" type relationship. So Alex and Fred have a relationship through Mary. Alex --> Mary --> Fred.

For example:
Input: Fred, 
Output: Mary, John, Alex

Input: Alex, 
Output: Mary, Fred, John

I'm using this example to try an learn recursion, so I have a recursion solution in mind, but am not sure if this can be done iteratively or how to build the proper recursion to solve this.

Comment: any code to show us?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some kind of graph search as a general solution for your problem. Then, each connected component represents set of people who know each other directly or via another person.

In your case, the graph looks like this:

[image: relationships graph]

Therefore, start from a person specified in your query and visit all descendant vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was able to whip up a simple DFS that seems to solve the problem at hand!

Answer (score 0):

you can level search the dict to find all relationship.

```
relationships = {"Fred": ["Mary", "John"],
                 "Mary": ["Fred", "Alex"],
                 "John": ["Fred"]
                 "Alex": ["Mary"]}

def findRelation(name):
    res = relationships.get(name)
    next = set(res)
    visited = set()
    while next:
        current = []
        for friend in next:
            if friend in visited: continue 
            visited.add(friend)
            item = relationships.get(friend)
            if item:
                res.extend(item)
                current.extend(item)
        next = set(current)
    return set(res)- set([name])


findRelation('Fred')
set(['John', 'Alex', 'Mary'])

findRelation('Alex')
set(['John', 'Mary', 'Fred'])
```